# Gcm xmpp limit of handling large number of users: Is it Limited or Unlimited?

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a gcm xmpp based chat application.

I have read the google docs thoroughly.

But i'm unable to make myself sure about a few things:

1)Is there any limit on gcm ccs use like for example can the service handle more users like a billion users?

2)Is there any other limitations of gcm which will affect my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit in term of number of users. You need to comply with the terms of service, but as long as your use case is legitimate, you should not be limited.

Comment: I think this is the number of simultaneous workers you can use to send notifications.